# How do I correctly parse this XML? Python - ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm having trouble parsing this XML. I'm fairly new to python so I may not be understanding a concept, or I may be missing a step.

The XML chunk:

```
<result created="2015-12-05T12:46:00-06:00" host="www.systemmonitor.us"     status="OK">
<items>
 <client>
  <clientid>67300</clientid>
  <name>
    <![CDATA[ ACME Company ]]>
  </name>
<site>
  <siteid>85663</siteid>
  <name>
    <![CDATA[ Los Angeles ]]>
  </name>
  <workstations/>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>597207</id>
      <name>
        <![CDATA[ SERVER1 ]]>
      </name>
      <offline>
        <description>
           <![CDATA[ OFFLINE - MAINTENANCE MODE ]]>
        </description>
        <startdate>2015-11-25</startdate>
        <starttime>01:40:07</starttime>
      </offline>
     </server>
     <server>
      <id>2252213</id>
        <name>
          <![CDATA[ SERVER2 ]]>
        </name>
        <overdue>
         <description>
           <![CDATA[ Overdue ]]>
         </description>
         <startdate>2015-11-25</startdate>
         <starttime>01:57:40</starttime>
        </overdue>
      </server>
    </servers>
  </site>
</client>
```

I need to extract certain elements so I can PUSH those elements into our CRM system.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "https://www.systemmonitor.us/api/"
querystring = {"apikey":"SUPERSECRETAPIKEY","service":"list_failing_checks"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)
msg = response.text
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(msg))

client_ids = tree.find('clientid')

print client_ids
```

If I try to get the client_id from msg.find('clientid') it only returns an integer. 144. (I assume that is the number of times it is found in the xml.) If I use tree.find('clientid') I get []. I haven't tried to iterate over the data yet because I can't seem to even find it.

I think I've tried every other combination I can find and think of but I cannot get this resolved. find(), findall(), etc. My brain hurts from slamming it on the desk.

I would need to isolate clientid, name, overdue/description.

Can someone please explain what I have done incorrectly or what I am missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the full path:

```
client_ids = tree.find('items/client/clientid')
```

or search all occurences with:

```
client_ids = tree.findall('.//clientid')
```

To get the contents of the elements use for example

```
for client_id in client_ids:
    print client_id.text
```

Comment: Both return <Element 'clientid' at 0x10eba8d90>. Shouldn't it return 67300?

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. I can now see the steps clearly. I feel silly being this giddy over seeing a bunch of numbers finally appear.